# Booth bit-pair recoding technique

Tags: arithmetic, multiplication

In Booth's bit-pair recording technique how to multiply a multiplicand with -2 or 2? For example while multiplying 01101(+13, multiplicand) and 11010(-6, multiplier), we get 01101 x 0-1-2.

How to multiply the multiplicand using -2?

Comment: I thought the result is `1110110010`, I do not fully understand your notation, shouldn't you recode the multiplier to `0-11-10`?

Answer (score 1):

In bit recoding multiplication, e.g.   01101 times 0, -1, or -2.

- For multiplying with -1:
  Take 2's complement of 01101 i.e: 10011
- For multiplying with -2:
  Add 2's complement of 01101 i.e: 10011 + 10011= 100110

Comment: Take a look at the rendered answer before finalizing your post.

Answer (score 1):

multiplying with -2 : Take 2's complement and Shift Left one bit

Answer (score -1):

First you must come to thr lsb of bit pair recoding i.e say 0 -1 2. So here lsb is 2 it means we must multiply 10 with multiplicand because based in the recoding table if it is positive 2 then we multiply and same procedure must be followed for next bit i.e -1 and so on

Comment: I have troubling following what you're saying. Can you please clean up the language and maybe check the chain of reasoning?